# Android get the date difference in minutes

Tags: android, date

I am trying to get the difference of two dates and get the results in minutes. i have the two dates in milliseconds

```
 long start = 1447143052593L;
 long end = 1447146592540L;
```

output of above is

`I/System.out﹕ 03:10:52
 I/System.out﹕ 04:09:52`

what i expect to be `0:59`

And i tried to get the difference in the below way, it does not work.

```
    long mills = end - start;

    long Hours = mills/(1000 * 60 * 60);
    long Mins = mills % (1000*60*60);
    String diff= Hours + ":" + Mins;
```

And the when i print the `String diff` i get the result as below

```
I/System.out﹕ 0:3539947
```

Comment: "it does not work" is never enough information. What result did you get? What result did you expect? (Hint: you're currently finding the "millisecond within the hour"... you might want to think about dividing by the number of milliseconds in a minute...) You should also consider what you want to happen if `end < start`.

Comment: i edited my question, hope it will be clear

Comment: Right. So do you undrstand *why* it's getting that result? Think about what the remainder operator does.

Answer (score 1):

try this approach:

```
long Hours  = mills / (1000 * 60 * 60);
long Mins  = (mills - Hours * (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the correct way, but your `Mins` now has the milliseconds that are remaining after the hours, instead of the minutes that are remaining.

This should work:

```
long Mins = (mills % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60); //make it minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you just need to make a Date object

```
Date startDate = new Date(start);
Date endDate = new Date(end);
int startminutes = startDate.getMinutes();
int endminutes = endDate.getMinutes();
```

And i say usually because it looks like it has been deprecated some time ago (while i hope it should be still working).

Looks like now they want we to use the Calendar class for this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, this is a really, really bad way of doing things. There's no need to use Date or Calendar for this.

Comment: I know it can be done without this, but why you say its a really bad way? by not taking account of the timezone or what?

Comment: Because `Date.getMinutes()` *does* use the local time zone, when there's no indication that that's desirable. There's a reason all those Date members are deprecated...

Comment: I was thinking if this is only to get a minute difference the time zone isnt critical while both dates are parsed the same way.

Comment: But what if the start and end minutes are in different UTC offsets? You could end up with two times that occurred 25 minutes apart, but with an answer of 10 due to a difference of 15 minutes in UTC offset. While time zone transitions which aren't whole hours are rare, they're not unheard of - and fundamentally, this is the wrong API for the job.